# Unable to infer schema when loading file

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

below code is working file when running in pyspark shell, but its failing when execution in spark-submit master-yarn.

What wrong am I doing here?

```
   from datetime import date, timedelta
   import pandas as pd
   import os, sys
    startd = '20140101'
    endd=str(sys.argv[1])
    currd=str(sys.argv[2])
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    base = "s3://metadata_v1/DATE="
    dstart = pd.to_datetime(startd).date()
    dend = pd.to_datetime(endd).date()

    s3 = []
    days = [dstart + timedelta(days=x) for x in range((dend - dstart).days + 1) if (dstart + timedelta(days=x)).weekday() == 5]
    for i in days:
        s3.append(base + i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    
    data = spark.read.option("header", "True").option("delimiter", "|").option("basePath","s3://metadata_v1/").csv(s3)
```

Error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Unable to infer schema for CSV. It must be specified manually.;'
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the schema manually?

Comment: header true with lower case?

Comment: Schema influence triggers an entire load/read of the file, which from S3 is slow and possibly expensive. Why not do it once for a minimal CSV, print it and then declare it in future. Otherwise you double your download time and $

Answer (score 0):

It could happen when some of your csv files contain header row, which some columns can't be loaded when trying to convert the data types for some columns. You can try to remove the header row in each CSV file before reading into dataframe.